# Почему всегда одно значение?

Tags: php

```
<? $i = 0; foreach($article->images as $val):?>
   <? $style = ($i>2) ? 'hidden' : 'visible';?>
<? endforeach; $i++;?>
```

Если `$i > 2`, все равное значение `$style = visible`

Почему?

Comment: А вот и нет, $i не больше двух. Если вы сделаете нормальное построчное форматирование кода, то увидите, что в цикле $i не изменяется никак и равен нулю.

Comment: Упс, $i++ не там..спасибо

Comment: в случае обычных списков вообще достаточно такого варианта

    foreach ($article->images as $key => $value) {
        $style = $key > 2 ? 'a' : 'b';
    }